# Grafana dashboard graph not showing data

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am new to grafana. My dashboard has bunch of graphs, one of those shows configured
prometheus data all fine but others including the health metrics show no data at all. It's exact same data source that works fine for the working graph. Does anybody know how to debug this?